# MS SQL Trigger for a Booking Cancellation

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

Novice At SQL trying to teach myself so apologies if question seems basic.

I need to create a trigger to be actioned when a booking is cancelled. This will also need to check if the party that has cancelled have also made any additional activity bookings in another table and subsequently remove these from the system.

So far i have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BookingCancellation ON Booking
FOR UPDATE
AS
  DECLARE @Cancellation char(8)
  IF @Cancellation = 'yes'
  BEGIN
    PRINT ('There has been a cancellation')
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
  END
```

But i dont know how to extend the trigger to check whether the party have made any subsequent external activity bookings and how they would be removed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why is there a rollback in there ? The rollback will cancel your booking cancellation so the booking can never get cancelled anymore

Comment: If you're new to SQL, you may not be aware that you can create Foreign Keys that can Cascade Deletes so that "child" rows are automatically removed when a "parent" row is.

Comment: Basically, if bookingID 1 gets cancelled. I want to be able to create a trigger that will delete any records that correlate to that booking, such as an activity they might have booked

Comment: You are much better off wrapping all of this logic up in a stored procedure, and calling that stored procedure to cancel a booking. Triggers should always be avoided.